# DIfferentiating between multiple event listeners

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

Can someone explain where my thinking goes wrong here ?
I have a class that adds a mousedown event listener to a specified canvas.
I make two instances of the class attached to two different canvases.
I expect to get responses from both instances but all responses say they're from the second instance.

```
class Mycanvas{
  constructor (canvas,name){
    self = this;
    this.name=name;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
  }
  function mousedown(){console.log(self.name)}
}
let mycanvas1 = Mycanvas(canvas1,'1');
let mycanvas2 = Mycanvas(canvas2,'2');
```

BUT, this code works fine :

```
class Mycanvas{
  constructor (canvas,name){
    this.name=name;
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ()=>console.log(this.name));
  }
}
let mycanvas1 = Mycanvas(canvas1,'1');
let mycanvas2 = Mycanvas(canvas2,'2');
```

Comment: Because 1. `self` is a global variable (it's window.self) so you overwrite it every time a new Class is created. 2. Why use `self = this` in a Class (or anywhere else, really)? You absolutely don't need it.

Comment: `this.self=this` would have also worked fine (albeit useless as @JeremyThille said) because then `self` isnt a global variable.

Comment: The solution is [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484) (also relevant: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)) but the problem is *also* that you make an [implicit global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Which is detailed in [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when should I use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488)

Comment: @Jamiec how would `this.self=this` work? The problem is the value of `this` missing - how would you get the correct value of `this` through `this`?

Comment: @VLAZ if in that same example the method were changed to `function mousedown(){console.log(this.self.name)}`. It's pointless as I said but it would work as expected (unless im missing something which is entirely possible)

Comment: I had indeed also missed the lack of `new`

Comment: Damn and blast it. The code is paraphrased from more extensive code where "new" was used but "let" was omitted in  "let self=this". Apologies for getting people to debug my mistakes.

Comment: I do think the "let self=this" is OK coding practice though. It is one of the three ways I have been told of to pass "this" to the listener function so that it can access the property of my object.

Comment: "*I do think the "let self=this" is OK coding practice though.*" but it cannot work if you declare the variable in one scope and try to use it in another where the variable is not present. [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431) `let self` means it's visible in the constructor, not in other methods.

Comment: Apologies again - mousedown was meant to be in the constructor function scope

Answer (score 0):

You invoke `Mycanvas(canvas1,'1')` directly (without the `new` keyword), which, I believe, only calls its constructor without instanciating a new Class. This doesn't output the expected result and makes you believe you need the `self=this` hack. But classes work like this :

```js
class Mycanvas{
  constructor (canvas, name){
    this.name=name;
    this.canvas = canvas;
  }
  logMyName() {
     this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', () => console.log(`My name is ${this.name}`));
  }
}

let mycanvas1 = new Mycanvas(canvas1,'1');
mycanvas1.logMyName();

let mycanvas2 = new Mycanvas(canvas2,'2');
mycanvas2.logMyName();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: grey solid 1px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Jeremy. Profuse apologies : the omission of new was a copy problem but the omission of let was a real problem. One day I might get used to javascript global variables , until then I'll stick a post-it note on my screen saying check local variables declarations FIRST. I think one of the self hack or arrow function or mousedown.bind(this)  are needed.

Comment: ? No, why would you need a hack or even a `.bind(this)`? Run my example. When you click canvas1 it says '1' and when you click canvas2 it says '2'. No `this`, no `bind`, no hack. Just a clean class.

Comment: My point was simply that as the mousedown function gets more complicated and the constructor and number of properties gets larger the arrow function becomes less ofan obvious choice.